# Instantiation on MongoClient produces error

Tags: mongodb, instantiationexception

Despite all the documentation that says beyond MongoDB 3.7 the MongoClient class can be instantiated, my Eclipse IDE shouts that MongClient cannot be instantiated. What could be the problem here ?

[image: MongoClient Instantiation error on Eclipse IDE.]

```
public class MongoDBExample 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String result = null;
        System.out.println("Making a connection to MongoDB..!");
        MongoClient mongo_client = new MongoClient(); // ("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        result = mongo_client.getClass().toString();
        System.out.println("Result : " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: From 3.7, the new API should be used like this: `MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();`

Comment: Be sure to `import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to instatiate `MongoClient` with the Legacy MongoDB Java Driver API way.

Since version 3.7, you should do it this way:

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

public class MongoConnect {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            MongoClient mongo_client_constructor1 = MongoClients.create(); // ("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            MongoClient mongo_client_constructor2 = MongoClients.create("mongodb://hostOne:27017,hostTwo:27018");

        }
}
```

The differences between the MongoDB Java Driver Legacy API and New API can be found clearly explained [here](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/driver/getting-started/quick-start/)

Also see the version 3.9 Javadoc for [MongoClients](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/MongoClients.html), a factory for MongoClient instances.

Comment: Thank you for that information Alexandre. I got lost in the maze of documentation available for multiple versions of the Java driver.

Comment: I'm glad it help you. Please upvote & accept the answer as correct.